# Pygame does not recognize number pad?

Tags: pygame

i use a small USB number pad/number keyboard for my Raspberry. It works well but my problem is, that it does not work with Pygame. I want to use the RETURN key with:

```
 elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
  if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN....
```

But it does not work. Using a "normal" big keyboard works well with Pygame. Can someone help?

Comment: It means, that Pygame recognize the button from the big keyboard

Comment: yep, i mean that i can write in the editor with it or type in simple numbers

Comment: yep! it works well

Comment: read the PyGame documentation ... the answer is there

Answer (score 1):

The PyGame library treats keypad keys different from normal keys. For instance, the normal enter key is defined as `pygame.K_RETURN` while the keypad enter key is `pygame.K_KP_ENTER`, so you should replace `K_RETURN` with `K_KP_ENTER` in your code. You can find a full list of the key codes [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).